# Like, Reblog, and Follow functions

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to create a really Like, Reblog, and Follow function in my PermalinksPagination section of my coding on Tumblr.

It seems that most Themes place these functions between the `{block:Posts}` and `{/block:posts}`, but I am trying to put these functions in between the `{block:PermalinkPagination}` and `{/block:PermalinkPagination}`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845538/hyperlink-like-reblog-and-follow

Answer (score 1):

To insert a like- or reblog-button, simply input this code wherever you'd like it to be:

```
{ReblogButton size="21" color="black"}
{LikeButton size="20" color="black"}
```