# Hyperlink: Like, Reblog, and follow

Tags: html

Is there a way to just Hyperlink the like, reblog, and follow functions on tumblr? I just want to write my code like this

```
<a href="{reblogURL}">reblog</a>
```

and it work wherever. But it doesn't. WHY?

Comment: "WHY?" It doesn't work because you wrote it wrong. As for your question please consider reading [ask].

Comment: I Googled this for you and found this: http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/4805059547/reblog-link-in-your-post  Your link should be `<a href="{ReblogURL}">reblog</a>` (note the upper-case `R`).

Comment: Please read the [Tumblr Developer Docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes).

Comment: Thank you! I did figure out how to add the reblog option, but I am still stuck on the like and follow function. Seems a little more complicated... I would love help. Of course the simpler the better when it comes to coding. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested; for 'Reblog' link you can do:

```
<a href="{ReblogURL}" title="Reblog"> Reblog </a>
```

Then for 'Follow' link you can do:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/follow/{name}" title="Follow {name}"> Follow </a>
```

*If you'll use this in your primary blog theme; to check how it works    you have to log out, 'cause you can't follow your primary blog from    your same primary blog.

*This way you can not follow/unfollow in one click, like a usual link    it'll    take you to the follow page and there you can follow or    unfollow the    user.

As much knowledge i have, for liking tumblr provides only like button, nothing like a text link that you can like/unlike by clicking.

So as you want to use text only, you can direct the link to permalink page where people can like it. By default Tumblr has 'Like' and 'Reblog' button in permalink page.

You can do it something like:

```
<a href="{Permalink}" title="Like"> Like </a>     
You should use the above inside {block:Posts} and {/block:Posts}.
```

This could be a solution, but it no longer works. Just writing the link, 'cause maybe you can do something from this idea : [here (link)](http://like-button.tumblr.com/).

I think that's all i can help for now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm going to give it a shot right now. Too bad that you can't follow or unfollow in one motion. But I think this might do. Duncan :)

Comment: The follow function works!!!! Thank you soooo much.